# Angular 2 route wildcard with auxiliary route syntax

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Say I have routes defined as such, and only one router-outlet (no aux outlet actually exists):

```
   export const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'user', redirectTo: 'user', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'admin', redirectTo: 'admin', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];
```

But say for whatever reason in the URL I type in `localhost/(aux:foo)` the wildcard does not match and an exception is thrown:

`Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'foo'`

Am I able to catch routes like this and handle them some other way? Granted the possibility that a user actually provided such a URL is low, I still think there should be a way to gracefully handle it?

Comment: did you manage to find any solution for this?